# Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that $\mathcal{N}(A)^\perp = \mathcal{R}(A^T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that $\mathcal{N}(A)^\perp = \mathcal{R}(A^T)$.

I was given this proof by a book:

*Demostración*. Take arbitrary $x\in\mathcal{N}(A)\implies Ax = 0 \implies y^TAx =0, \forall y$. But $y^TAx = (A^Ty)^Tx$. Thus, $Ax = 0$ iff $x$ is orthogonal to all vectors of the form $A^Ty$, i.e., $x\in\mathcal{R}(A^T)^\perp$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we find our desired $\mathcal{N}(A)^\perp = \mathcal{R}(A^T)$.

Before the last line, are they implicitly showing "$\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{R}(A^T)^\perp$. Take the perp and get $\mathcal{N}(A)^\perp = (\mathcal{R}(A^T)^\perp)^\perp = \mathcal{N}(A)^\perp = \mathcal{R}(A^T)$"?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is in the body: *are they implicitly showing "..."?*

Comment: Yes, and still the proof is not complete: they only showed that $\mathcal N(A) \subseteq \mathcal R(A^\textsf{T})^\perp$, that is, if $Ax=0$, then $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\mathcal R(A^\textsf{T})$. The converse is also easy: if $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\mathcal R(A^\textsf{T})$, then $y^\textsf{T}Ax = (A^\textsf{T}y)^\textsf{T}x=0$ holds for each $y$, so that $(Ax)^\textsf{T}Ax = 0$, and this of course implies $Ax=0$. Hence $\mathcal N(A) = \mathcal R(A^\textsf{T})^\perp$, and taking $(\_)^\perp$ we are done (since $(W^\perp)^\perp = W$).

Comment: I understand! Thank you for that! @azif00